# how to aggregate a data.frame when group names are presented in different rows

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data.frame like this

```
df=data.frame(
grp=c("group1","s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","group2","s6","s7","s8","group2","s9","s10","group3","s11","s12","s13","s14"),
gname=c("gene1",0.00,0.05,0.01,0.01,0.01,"gene1",0.063,0.005,0.015,"gene2",0.07,0.00,"gene3",0.046,0.007,0.011,0.012),
score=c(0.989003844,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.988334014,NA,NA,NA,0.983461712,NA,NA,0.982339339,NA,NA,NA,NA)
)

> df
      grp gname      score
1  group1 gene1 0.9890038
2      s1     0        NA
3      s2  0.05        NA
4      s3  0.01        NA
5      s4  0.01        NA
6      s5  0.01        NA
7  group2 gene1 0.9883340
8      s6 0.063        NA
9      s7 0.005        NA
10     s8 0.015        NA
11 group2 gene2 0.9834617
12     s9  0.07        NA
13    s10     0        NA
14 group3 gene3 0.9823393
15    s11 0.046        NA
16    s12 0.007        NA
17    s13 0.011        NA
18    s14 0.012        NA
```

based on the group and gene names, the df could be divided to 4 section.the following picture shows this 4 section.

[image]

I am going to aggregate the `df`  for each sections to find the `max` of `df$score` and `length` of `df$grp` based on columns `df$grp` and `df$gname`. the following df shows the Expected result.

```
grp     gname   max.score   length
group1  gene1   0.989003844   5
group2  gene1   0.988334014   3
group2  gene2   0.983461712   2
group3  gene3   0.982339339   4
```

and the following picture shows how the result is earned.
[image]

how could I perform `aggregate(score~grp+gname,df,max)` and `aggregate(grp~grp+gname,df,length)` for each section and save the results in a data.frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that each group starts with a non missing score, followed by missing values, then a combination of `cumsum/is.na` and `tapply` will do the trick.

Start by creating an aggregation variable `f`.

```
f <- cumsum(!is.na(df$score))
```

Now see what are the results lengths. The top row of numbers are the values of the `"names"` attribute, the lengths are the bottom row. These lengths include the `"group*"` row, so in the final dataframe, subtract 1.

```
tapply(f, f, length)
#1 2 3 4 
#6 4 3 5
```

Create the result the question asks for.

```
result <- cbind(df[!is.na(df$score), ], length = tapply(f, f, length) - 1)

result
#      grp gname     score length
#1  group1 gene1 0.9890038      5
#7  group2 gene1 0.9883340      3
#11 group2 gene2 0.9834617      2
#14 group3 gene3 0.9823393      4
```

If you further want consecutive row names,

```
row.names(result) <- NULL
```

Comment: You need to subtract 1 from the length to account for the row that serves as "sub-header".

Comment: @Alexis Right, I had just noticed that. Give me a moment... Done.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp1 = cumsum(grepl("group", grp))) %>%
  mutate(length = n() -1) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp1)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  grp    gname score length
#  <fct>  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 group1 gene1 0.989      5
#2 group2 gene1 0.988      3
#3 group2 gene2 0.983      2
#4 group3 gene3 0.982      4
```